# Why does npx install webpack every time?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, npx

I have a JavaScript app I'm bundling with webpack. Per the docs, I'm using this command to start bundling:

```
npx webpack
```

Each time I get this output:

```
npx: installed 1 in 2.775s
```

I've verified that the webpack command exists in my `./node_modules/.bin` directory where npx is looking. Can anyone think of why it's downloading webpack every time? It can take up to 7 seconds to complete this step, which is slowing down my builds.

Comment: I think the "installed 1" is not about webpack but due to a weird bug which makes it install a package "prefix" every time you run npx. It's a weird bug: https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/148

Comment: that kills npx for me..

Comment: solution is to install npm-run globally

Comment: I cannot reproduce on `npx` 6.14.11 after `npm install webpack;npm install webpack-cli;npx webpack` it runs immediately without redownload. Or do you want to not install webpack with `npm install`? Can you provide versions of everything if your behavior differs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Old answer**:

`npx` doesn't reuse previously installed packages, instead it pulls down that package's dependencies every time that you run it.

**Update** on 06 May 2022 for newer versions of `npx` e.g. ver. 8.3.0:

Now `npx` does use previously installed packages without need to reinstall anything! Looks like `npm` team fixed old issue some time ago, not sure which version was first that received this fix.

> npx allows you to run an arbitrary command from an npm package
> (either one installed locally, or fetched remotely), in a similar
> context as running it via npm run.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npx

Comment: A note for other beginners, on `npx` 6.14.11 when I do `npm install --save vaca;npx vaca` the execution does not redownload. It only redownloads every time if I don't do the `npm install` such that `vaca` is not in `node_modules`. Either this answer meant to address only the case of "from an arbitrary directory", or npx changed since.

Comment: @Maksim, Could you please give a reference to this information? Thanks!

Comment: I updated my old answer with new information. Thanks for pointing me out to the changes.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [laggingreflex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49302438/why-does-npx-install-webpack-every-time/68421887#comment85607199_49302438). It was probably not `webpack` that's being installed in your case each time. Refer [this issue](https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/148), it is of around the same time. I don't think it is applicable to newer versions.

---

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58642519/11613622) is misleading, or at least I don't quite understand its context.

Quoting [the readme](https://github.com/npm/npx#description):

> Executes `<command>` either from a local `node_modules/.bin`, or from a central cache, installing any packages needed in order for `<command>` to run.

> By default, `npx` will check whether `<command>` exists in `$PATH`, or in the local project binaries, and execute that. If `<command>` is not found, it will be installed prior to execution.

Quoting [release blog](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/162869356040/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner):

> `npx` has basically no overhead if invoking an already-installed binary  —  it's clever enough to load the code for the tool directly into the current running node process!

> Calling `npx <command>` when `<command>` isn't already in your `$PATH` will automatically install a package with that name from the `npm` registry for you, and invoke it. When it’s done, the installed package won't be anywhere in your globals, so you won’t have to worry about pollution in the long-term.

Although the above referenced `npx` as a separate package is now deprecated and `npx` is now a part of `npm-cli`, but the essence is still same, and can also be verified by the [official docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npx):

> This command allows you to run an arbitrary command from an `npm` package (either one installed locally, or fetched remotely).

> If any requested packages are not present in the local project dependencies, then they are installed to a folder in the `npm` cache, which is added to the `PATH` environment variable in the executed process.